# Use OR conditions in WHERE clause as column names in result

Tags: mysql, sql

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc2de59/2):**

```
CREATE TABLE Sales (
    Product_ID VARCHAR(255),
    Country VARCHAR(255),
    Sales_Volume VARCHAR(255)
);

INSERT INTO Sales
(Product_ID, Country, Sales_Volume)
VALUES 
("P001", "US", "500"),
("P001", "US", "100"),
("P003", "US", "800"),
("P002", "DE", "300"),
("P001", "DE", "700"),
("P002", "NL", "200"),
("P002", "NL", "400");
```

In the table I have the the `Sales` in different `Countries`. 
Now, I want to sum up the `Sales` per `Country`. 
The expected result should look like this:

```
                US             DE 
P001           600            700
P002           NULL           300
P003           800            NULL
```

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT
Product_ID,
Country,
SUM(Sales_Volume)
FROM Sales
WHERE 
Country = "US" 
OR Country ="DE"
GROUP BY 1,2;
```

This query basically works but instead of displaying the `Country` as `column name` it displays the country as `value`.

What do I need to change in my SQL to get the result I need?

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code. With that in mind, query-wise, I would (pretty much) stick with what you've got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Product_ID,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Country = 'US' THEN Sales_Volume ELSE 0 END) as US,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Country = 'DE' THEN Sales_Volume ELSE 0 END) as DE
FROM Sales
GROUP BY Product_ID;
```

Comment: And here's the Fiddle, since I had it typed up, but Gordon posted first. :) http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc2de59/12

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cc2de59/10

Answer (score 0):

If you only need for 2 countries or less number of countries that you can hard code in your query -

```
SELECT
Product_ID,
sum(IF(country='DE',sales_volume,NULL)) 'DE',
sum(IF(country='US',sales_volume,NULL)) 'US'
FROM Sales
```