# Retrieving data from two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, union

I havetwo tables, Table A with Customer ID as well Sales from online purchase and Table B with Customer IDs as well as Sales from Store Purchase. My Output should consist of Customer ID from both tables with a column that says, "Store", "Online", "Both" depending on the kind of purchase the customer made.

Comment: Please show your current code

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To help us help you, please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Take a look at this [well-structured question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60453346/use-or-conditions-in-where-clause-as-column-names-in-result), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60608125/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example for database-related questions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please tag the actual RDBMS of interest.

Comment: Please read this guide on how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use `union all` and some `case` logic:

```
select customerid,
       (case when max(is_online) = 1 and max(is_instore) = 1 then 'both'
             when max(is_online) = 1 then 'online'
             else 'instore'
        end) as grouping
from ((select customerid, 1 as is_online, 0 as is_instore
       from a
      ) union all
      (select customerid, 0 as is_online, 1 as is_instore
       from b
      ) 
     ) ab
group by customerid;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
 c.customer_id, 
 case when count(*) = 2 then 'both' else c.location end as location
from (
       select a.customer_id, 'store' as location from ta a 
       union 
       select b.customer_id, 'online' as location from tb b
     ) c 
group by c.customer_id
```

Comment: Some explanation of your answer would help others understand it better.